# "Zippable" class for haskell?

Tags: haskell

In an attempt to get familiar with the great ideas such as `Foldable`, `Functor`, etc. I'm writing a data structure for 2*2 matrix. It isn't for real use, so I thought this naive implementation is a good start:

```
data Matrix2d a = M2 a a a a
```

I want this to be a `Num` instance

```
instance Num a => Num (Matrix2d a) where
    (M2 a0 b0 c0 d0) + (M2 a1 b1 c1 d1) = M2 (a0+a1) (b0+b1) (c0+c1) (d0+d1)
    -- ....
```

This does not seem right. I don't want to type `+` five times for this obvious definition. Certainly there's room for more abstraction. I'd prefer something like

```
(+) = fzipWith (+) -- f does not mean anything here
```

This is actually easy to implement:

```
class Zippable z where
    fzipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> z a -> z b -> z c

instance Zippable Matrix2 where
    fzipWith f (M2 x y z w) (M2 a b c d) = M2 (f x a) (f y b) (f z c) (f w d)
```

however, I couldn't find anything ready-to-use in hoogle. I find it odd because this kind of abstraction seems quite natural. There's `Foldable`, there's `Functor` --- why not `Zippable`?

Questions:

- Is there any module that provides this functionality?
- If not (I believe this is the case), what options do I have? Is defining my own class the best choice, or is there any better alternative?

Comment: Learn you a haskell: http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids

Comment: This isn't a super practical answer, but [F-algebras](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/constructions-on-typeclasses-part-1-f-algebras/) provide a very regular structure for getting functions like `(+)` for free.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do much with just `Functor`, but with `Applicative` you can do

```
fzipWith f za zb = f <$> za <*> zb
```

The default instance for `Applicative []` won't do quite what you want; it will take *every* `a` with *every* `b`. But I believe there's a `ZipList` newtype somewhere that gives you an instance that zips the way you're expecting. (No, I don't know exactly where it lives.)

Note that this generalises to *any* number of arguments:

```
f <$> za <*> zb <*> zc <*> zd
```

so you don't need the `zipWith`, `zipWith3`, `zipWith4`, etc functions.

Comment: Could you add an example of implemention? I wrote [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/417585e7f6d54ddfc7fd) par your suggestion, is this all right?

Comment: The [default](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Data/Vec.agda#L69) `Applicative` instance for vectors encodes zipping. The translation to Haskell is straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

See the adjunctions package, and in particular [`Data.Functor.Rep.liftR2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.2.1/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html#v:liftR2).

Your `Matrix2` is a representable functor.